# Animation and gamification

Tags: animation, gamification, user-engagement

I'm trying to add a few animations to my application targeted towards teens, specifically animations that increase user engagement.

Similar to how twitter introduced the heart animation.. it's almost addicting. Are there any stats available as to how the animation compared to not having an animation? I'm guessing it outperformed what they had previously.

[image]

Another problem I'm struggling with is coming up with inspiration for these types of animations. Are there examples of simple, highly engaging, gamified animations that really work?

I'd love to know if y'all have any experience in this and if you had a resource that you find helpful. I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Please check for prefers-reduced-motion, because animation can trigger migraines, motion sickness, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Functional UI animation will always enhance user experience if used correctly (i.e. don't overdo it).

While I don't know about how it affected twitter's engagement, I recommend reading this article that explains in full detail how UX animation should be used and how useful it can be:

http://www.callumhart.com/blog/using-animation-to-design-better-user-experiences

On the inspiration side, there is a website that literally does just this: curates UI motion around the web and collects it all for your inspiration. The website is:
https://motion-ux.com